# env file for rails app not in right place? not being seen by rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

so first time working with rails i work with django

I tried deploying the local server and it failed because of a key error known as `s3_bucket_name` because I didn't have the ENV file which contained the variables

so then i got the ENV file and placed it in the root of the application.

then I tried to launch the app with no go.

Then I ran the command rake.

Which it complained:

```
C:\Users\chris\Documents\suitsandtables>rake
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 12.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 12.0.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
```

so then I ran what it suggested with `--trace`

and I got the same returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\Users\chris\Documents\suitsandtables>bundle exec rake --trace
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
rake aborted!
KeyError: key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME"
C:/Users/chris/Documents/suitsandtables/config/initializers/s3.rb:4:in `fetch'
C:/Users/chris/Documents/suitsandtables/config/initializers/s3.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
C:/Users/chris/Documents/suitsandtables/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
C:/Users/chris/Documents/suitsandtables/test/test_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
C:/Users/chris/Documents/suitsandtables/test/controllers/menus_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:14:in `block in require_files'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in `require_files'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:67:in `rake_run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:216:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rake:22:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => test
```

the contents of the env file is as follows with sensitive info removed

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME=sat-paperclip-prod-heroku
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= removed
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= removed
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
GOOGLE_API_KEY= removed
```

can i get some help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by using [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) in `config/initializers/s3.rb`. That's a good thing. Don't change that. Your app requires that ENV value to work correctly, so it breaks if it's not set. (Everything within `config/initializers/` runs on startup. This `s3.rb` file is not part of Rails core and was added by the app's author.)

Make sure your `Gemfile` has `dotenv-rails` specified. If it doesn't, add it (see https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) and type `bundle` in the terminal from your Rails root directory. (Note that `dotenv-rails` is also not part of Rails core.)

The root of your Rails app is the directory containing containing the files `Gemfile`, `Gemfile.lock`, etc. and the directories `app/`, `bin/`, `config/`, `db/`, `lib/`, etc. (i.e. `C:/Users/chris/Documents/suitsandtables/`). You can confirm by jumping into the Rails console (`rails c` or `bundle exec rails c` in the terminal) and typing `Rails.root`.

The env file should be named `.env` (thus the name of gem: `dotenv`) and should be located in your Rails root directory.

You can test your `.env` file through `rails c` by typing:

```
# in the rails console
ENV                   # your whole environment in a Hash
ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"] # your bucket name
```

Test all the environment values you're looking for. CaSe MaTtErS.

If you have any Rails servers or tasks running, restart them to pick up these changes.

The expected result of typing `bundle exec rake` is to run the tests. If you want to run the app itself, use `rails s` or `bundle exec rails s`.

p.s. Don't `git add/commit` your `.env`. It contains secrets. Make sure it is `gitignore`d.

Comment: well done @eddroid thank you. I am currently on a windows Machine normally I dev in linux. But for the sake of ease conditionering I am inheriting this program from someone else, I switch to windows. making the ENV file to a .ENV file is easy in linux but in windows I am having trouble. Currently working on a work around, once I find it I'll see what happens with your suggeestions. I really appreciate you taking the time!